# Altbeacon library: eddystone beacon going out of region (apparently) for no reason

Tags: android, altbeacon, eddystone

I've a beacon trasmitting at 10Hz (eddystone UID, eddystone TLM and iBeacon) while moving, when movement stops it keeps trasmitting for 1 more minute and then stops.
My target is to detect when the beacon stop moving so I used the following code, which actually is the basic example provided on altbeacon webpage with customized timing:

```
public class BeaconReaderActivity extends Activity implements BeaconConsumer, MonitorNotifier, RangeNotifier {

    private BeaconManager beaconManager;
    private Region beaconRegion;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_beacon_reader);

        beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
        beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser()
            .setBeaconLayout(BeaconParser.EDDYSTONE_UID_LAYOUT));
        beaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser()
            .setBeaconLayout(BeaconParser.EDDYSTONE_TLM_LAYOUT));
        beaconManager.setRegionStatePeristenceEnabled(false);

        beaconManager.setForegroundScanPeriod(101L);
        beaconManager.setForegroundBetweenScanPeriod(0L);
        beaconManager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(101L);
        beaconManager.setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod(0L);

        beaconRegion = new Region(
            "beacon-region",
            null,
            Identifier.parse(INSTANCE_ID),
            null);

        beaconManager.bind(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBeaconServiceConnect() {
        beaconManager.addMonitorNotifier(this);
        try {
           beaconManager.startMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(beaconRegion);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void didEnterRegion(Region region) {
        beaconManager.addRangeNotifier(this);
        try {
            beaconManager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(beaconRegion);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void didExitRegion(Region region) {
        try {
            beaconManager.stopRangingBeaconsInRegion(beaconRegion);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int i, Region region) {
        switch (i) {
            case 0:
                Log.e("BEACON MANAGER", "Beacon out of region");
                break;
            case 1:
                Log.e("BEACON MANAGER", "Beacon entered in region");
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(final Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {
        Log.e("BEACON MANAGER", "Frame received");
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I met two kind of issues:

1. sometimes it takes really long for beacon to enter the region;
2. often the beacon exits from the region, seems for no reason, although the gap from the last frame received is much lower than 10secs (exit region period is still default one); below the logcat:

   ```
   04-24 11:46:04.669 8254-10315/com.applications.r08y.beaconreader E/BEACON MANAGER: Frame received
   04-24 11:46:04.838 8254-10316/com.applications.r08y.beaconreader E/BEACON MANAGER: Frame received
   04-24 11:46:04.983 8254-10317/com.applications.r08y.beaconreader E/BEACON MANAGER: Frame received
   04-24 11:46:05.199 8254-10323/com.applications.r08y.beaconreader E/BEACON MANAGER: Frame received
   04-24 11:46:05.375 8254-10324/com.applications.r08y.beaconreader E/BEACON MANAGER: Frame received
   04-24 11:46:05.527 8254-10325/com.applications.r08y.beaconreader E/BEACON MANAGER: Frame received
   04-24 11:46:05.697 8254-10328/com.applications.r08y.beaconreader E/BEACON MANAGER: Frame received
   04-24 11:46:05.884 8254-10332/com.applications.r08y.beaconreader E/BEACON MANAGER: Frame received
   04-24 11:46:06.028 8254-10333/com.applications.r08y.beaconreader E/BEACON MANAGER: Frame received
   04-24 11:46:06.179 8254-10334/com.applications.r08y.beaconreader E/BEACON MANAGER: Frame received
   04-24 11:46:06.380 8254-10340/com.applications.r08y.beaconreader E/BEACON MANAGER: Frame received
   04-24 11:46:06.536 8254-10341/com.applications.r08y.beaconreader E/BEACON MANAGER: Frame received
   04-24 11:46:06.688 8254-10342/com.applications.r08y.beaconreader E/BEACON MANAGER: Frame received
   04-24 11:46:06.862 8254-10348/com.applications.r08y.beaconreader E/BEACON MANAGER: Frame received
   04-24 11:46:06.999 8254-10350/com.applications.r08y.beaconreader E/BEACON MANAGER: Frame received
   04-24 11:46:07.204 8254-10351/com.applications.r08y.beaconreader E/BEACON MANAGER: Beacon out of region
   ```

Can somebody kindly explain me why this happen? Is there something I can do to make software more robust?

Thanks

**--- EDIT ---**

here's logcat after adding setDebug(True)

```
04-24 15:04:12.045 17067-17082/com.applications.r08y.beaconreader I/art: Debugger is active
04-24 15:04:12.187 17067-17067/com.applications.r08y.beaconreader I/System.out: Debugger has connected
04-24 15:04:12.187 17067-17067/com.applications.r08y.beaconreader I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
```

... waiting for debug to settle

```
04-24 15:04:14.790 17067-17067/com.applications.r08y.beaconreader I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
04-24 15:04:14.990 17067-17067/com.applications.r08y.beaconreader I/System.out: debugger has settled (1379)
04-24 15:04:15.077 17067-17067/com.applications.r08y.beaconreader I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
04-24 15:04:15.245 17067-17067/com.applications.r08y.beaconreader I/BeaconService: beaconService version 2.9 is starting up
04-24 15:04:15.247 17067-17067/com.applications.r08y.beaconreader W/BluetoothCrashResolver: Can't read macs from BluetoothCrashResolverState.txt
04-24 15:04:15.253 17067-17067/com.applications.r08y.beaconreader I/CycledLeScanner: This Android 5.0.  We are using new scanning APIs
04-24 15:04:15.261 17067-17067/com.applications.r08y.beaconreader W/ModelSpecificDistanceCalculator: App has no android.permission.INTERNET permission.  Cannot check for distance model updates
04-24 15:04:15.284 17067-17067/com.applications.r08y.beaconreader W/ModelSpecificDistanceCalculator: Cannot find match for this device.  Using default
04-24 15:04:15.284 17067-17067/com.applications.r08y.beaconreader W/ModelSpecificDistanceCalculator: Cannot find match for this device.  Using default
04-24 15:04:15.288 17067-17067/com.applications.r08y.beaconreader I/BeaconService: binding
04-24 15:04:15.313 17067-17169/com.applications.r08y.beaconreader I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
04-24 15:04:15.333 17067-17067/com.applications.r08y.beaconreader E/BEACON MANAGER: Beacon out of region
04-24 15:04:15.353 17067-17169/com.applications.r08y.beaconreader E/libEGL: cache file failed CRC check
04-24 15:04:15.433 17067-17067/com.applications.r08y.beaconreader I/BeaconService: start monitoring received
04-24 15:04:15.443 17067-17067/com.applications.r08y.beaconreader I/CycledLeScanner: Adjusted scanStopTime to be 101
04-24 15:04:38.403 17067-17087/com.applications.r08y.beaconreader I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 5309(314KB) AllocSpace objects, 1(20KB) LOS objects, 39% free, 1695KB/2MB, paused 10.900ms total 41.600ms
04-24 15:04:44.222 17067-17067/com.applications.r08y.beaconreader I/BluetoothLeScanner: startRegisteration: mLeScanClients={} ,callback=org.altbeacon.beacon.service.scanner.CycledLeScannerForLollipop$2@3b05192c
04-24 15:04:44.235 17067-17067/com.applications.r08y.beaconreader E/BluetoothLeScanner: application registeration exception
                                                                                    android.os.DeadObjectException
                                                                                        at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
                                                                                        at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:504)
                                                                                        at android.bluetooth.IBluetoothGatt$Stub$Proxy.registerClient(IBluetoothGatt.java:851)
                                                                                        at android.bluetooth.le.BluetoothLeScanner$BleScanCallbackWrapper.startRegisteration(BluetoothLeScanner.java:245)
                                                                                        at android.bluetooth.le.BluetoothLeScanner.startScan(BluetoothLeScanner.java:137)
                                                                                        at android.bluetooth.le.BluetoothLeScanner.startScan(BluetoothLeScanner.java:106)
                                                                                        at org.altbeacon.beacon.service.scanner.CycledLeScannerForLollipop.startScan(CycledLeScannerForLollipop.java:187)
                                                                                        at org.altbeacon.beacon.service.scanner.CycledLeScanner.scanLeDevice(CycledLeScanner.java:190)
                                                                                        at org.altbeacon.beacon.service.scanner.CycledLeScanner.finishScanCycle(CycledLeScanner.java:266)
                                                                                        at org.altbeacon.beacon.service.scanner.CycledLeScanner.scheduleScanCycleStop(CycledLeScanner.java:239)
                                                                                        at org.altbeacon.beacon.service.scanner.CycledLeScanner$1.run(CycledLeScanner.java:235)
                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5546)
                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:964)
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:759)
04-24 15:04:44.236 17067-17067/com.applications.r08y.beaconreader E/CycledLeScannerForLollipop: Scan Failed
04-24 15:04:44.236 17067-17067/com.applications.r08y.beaconreader E/CycledLeScannerForLollipop: Scan Failed
04-24 15:04:44.339 17067-17067/com.applications.r08y.beaconreader I/BluetoothLeScanner: startRegisteration: mLeScanClients={} ,callback=org.altbeacon.beacon.service.scanner.CycledLeScannerForLollipop$2@3b05192c
04-24 15:04:44.342 17067-17067/com.applications.r08y.beaconreader E/BluetoothLeScanner: application registeration exception
                                                                                    android.os.DeadObjectException
                                                                                        at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
                                                                                        at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:504)
                                                                                        at android.bluetooth.IBluetoothGatt$Stub$Proxy.registerClient(IBluetoothGatt.java:851)
                                                                                        at android.bluetooth.le.BluetoothLeScanner$BleScanCallbackWrapper.startRegisteration(BluetoothLeScanner.java:245)
                                                                                        at android.bluetooth.le.BluetoothLeScanner.startScan(BluetoothLeScanner.java:137)
                                                                                        at android.bluetooth.le.BluetoothLeScanner.startScan(BluetoothLeScanner.java:106)
                                                                                        at org.altbeacon.beacon.service.scanner.CycledLeScannerForLollipop.startScan(CycledLeScannerForLollipop.java:187)
                                                                                        at org.altbeacon.beacon.service.scanner.CycledLeScanner.scanLeDevice(CycledLeScanner.java:190)
                                                                                        at org.altbeacon.beacon.service.scanner.CycledLeScanner.finishScanCycle(CycledLeScanner.java:266)
                                                                                        at org.altbeacon.beacon.service.scanner.CycledLeScanner.scheduleScanCycleStop(CycledLeScanner.java:239)
                                                                                        at org.altbeacon.beacon.service.scanner.CycledLeScanner$1.run(CycledLeScanner.java:235)
                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5546)
                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:964)
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:759)
04-24 15:04:44.343 17067-17067/com.applications.r08y.beaconreader E/CycledLeScannerForLollipop: Scan Failed
04-24 15:04:44.343 17067-17067/com.applications.r08y.beaconreader E/CycledLeScannerForLollipop: Scan Failed
04-24 15:04:44.447 17067-17067/com.applications.r08y.beaconreader I/BluetoothLeScanner: startRegisteration: mLeScanClients={} ,callback=org.altbeacon.beacon.service.scanner.CycledLeScannerForLollipop$2@3b05192c
04-24 15:04:44.457 17067-17067/com.applications.r08y.beaconreader I/BluetoothLeScanner: startRegisteration: mLeScanClients={org.altbeacon.beacon.service.scanner.CycledLeScannerForLollipop$2@3b05192c=android.bluetooth.le.BluetoothLeScanner$BleScanCallbackWrapper@2aa317e2}
```

... scanning attempts ...

```
04-24 15:05:33.076 17067-17067/com.applications.r08y.beaconreader I/BluetoothLeScanner: startRegisteration: mLeScanClients={org.altbeacon.beacon.service.scanner.CycledLeScannerForLollipop$2@3b05192c=android.bluetooth.le.BluetoothLeScanner$BleScanCallbackWrapper@286a8874} ,callback=org.altbeacon.beacon.service.scanner.CycledLeScannerForLollipop$2@3b05192c
04-24 15:05:33.083 17067-17067/com.applications.r08y.beaconreader I/BluetoothLeScanner: startRegisteration: mLeScanClients={org.altbeacon.beacon.service.scanner.CycledLeScannerForLollipop$2@3b05192c=android.bluetooth.le.BluetoothLeScanner$BleScanCallbackWrapper@28a7a19d}
04-24 15:05:33.152 17067-18004/com.applications.r08y.beaconreader E/BEACON MANAGER: Beacon entered in region
04-24 15:05:33.152 17067-17067/com.applications.r08y.beaconreader I/BeaconService: start ranging received
04-24 15:05:33.189 17067-17067/com.applications.r08y.beaconreader I/BluetoothLeScanner: startRegisteration: mLeScanClients={org.altbeacon.beacon.service.scanner.CycledLeScannerForLollipop$2@3b05192c=android.bluetooth.le.BluetoothLeScanner$BleScanCallbackWrapper@28a7a19d} ,callback=org.altbeacon.beacon.service.scanner.CycledLeScannerForLollipop$2@3b05192c
04-24 15:05:33.195 17067-17067/com.applications.r08y.beaconreader I/BluetoothLeScanner: startRegisteration: mLeScanClients={org.altbeacon.beacon.service.scanner.CycledLeScannerForLollipop$2@3b05192c=android.bluetooth.le.BluetoothLeScanner$BleScanCallbackWrapper@30139a5b}
```

... frames received approx every 100msec

```
04-24 15:05:43.093 17067-18175/com.applications.r08y.beaconreader E/BEACON MANAGER: Frame received
04-24 15:05:43.207 17067-17067/com.applications.r08y.beaconreader I/BluetoothLeScanner: startRegisteration: mLeScanClients={org.altbeacon.beacon.service.scanner.CycledLeScannerForLollipop$2@3b05192c=android.bluetooth.le.BluetoothLeScanner$BleScanCallbackWrapper@13604c34} ,callback=org.altbeacon.beacon.service.scanner.CycledLeScannerForLollipop$2@3b05192c
04-24 15:05:43.223 17067-17067/com.applications.r08y.beaconreader I/BluetoothLeScanner: startRegisteration: mLeScanClients={org.altbeacon.beacon.service.scanner.CycledLeScannerForLollipop$2@3b05192c=android.bluetooth.le.BluetoothLeScanner$BleScanCallbackWrapper@6cff7a0}
04-24 15:05:43.231 17067-18176/com.applications.r08y.beaconreader E/BEACON MANAGER: Beacon out of region
04-24 15:05:43.232 17067-17067/com.applications.r08y.beaconreader I/BeaconService: stop ranging received
04-24 15:05:43.236 17067-18176/com.applications.r08y.beaconreader E/BEACON MANAGER: Frame received
04-24 15:05:43.328 17067-17067/com.applications.r08y.beaconreader I/BluetoothLeScanner: startRegisteration: mLeScanClients={org.altbeacon.beacon.service.scanner.CycledLeScannerForLollipop$2@3b05192c=android.bluetooth.le.BluetoothLeScanner$BleScanCallbackWrapper@6cff7a0} ,callback=org.altbeacon.beacon.service.scanner.CycledLeScannerForLollipop$2@3b05192c
04-24 15:05:43.340 17067-17067/com.applications.r08y.beaconreader I/BluetoothLeScanner: startRegisteration: mLeScanClients={org.altbeacon.beacon.service.scanner.CycledLeScannerForLollipop$2@3b05192c=android.bluetooth.le.BluetoothLeScanner$BleScanCallbackWrapper@3ccedcc}
```

... scanning

```
04-24 15:05:45.558 17067-17067/com.applications.r08y.beaconreader I/BluetoothLeScanner: startRegisteration: mLeScanClients={org.altbeacon.beacon.service.scanner.CycledLeScannerForLollipop$2@3b05192c=android.bluetooth.le.BluetoothLeScanner$BleScanCallbackWrapper@214d61fc} ,callback=org.altbeacon.beacon.service.scanner.CycledLeScannerForLollipop$2@3b05192c
04-24 15:05:45.590 17067-17067/com.applications.r08y.beaconreader I/BluetoothLeScanner: startRegisteration: mLeScanClients={org.altbeacon.beacon.service.scanner.CycledLeScannerForLollipop$2@3b05192c=android.bluetooth.le.BluetoothLeScanner$BleScanCallbackWrapper@6b5b085}
04-24 15:05:45.684 17067-18203/com.applications.r08y.beaconreader E/BEACON MANAGER: Beacon entered in region
04-24 15:05:45.684 17067-17067/com.applications.r08y.beaconreader I/BeaconService: start ranging received
04-24 15:05:45.695 17067-17067/com.applications.r08y.beaconreader I/BluetoothLeScanner: startRegisteration: mLeScanClients={org.altbeacon.beacon.service.scanner.CycledLeScannerForLollipop$2@3b05192c=android.bluetooth.le.BluetoothLeScanner$BleScanCallbackWrapper@6b5b085} ,callback=org.altbeacon.beacon.service.scanner.CycledLeScannerForLollipop$2@3b05192c
04-24 15:05:45.700 17067-17067/com.applications.r08y.beaconreader I/BluetoothLeScanner: startRegisteration: mLeScanClients={org.altbeacon.beacon.service.scanner.CycledLeScannerForLollipop$2@3b05192c=android.bluetooth.le.BluetoothLeScanner$BleScanCallbackWrapper@192100e7}
```

**--- EDIT 2 ---**
logcat with scantime 501L

```
04-24 19:25:35.423 19998-21049/com.applications.r08y.beaconreader E/BEACON MANAGER: Beacon entered in region
04-24 19:25:35.679 19998-21055/com.applications.r08y.beaconreader E/BEACON MANAGER: Frame received
04-24 19:25:36.206 19998-21061/com.applications.r08y.beaconreader E/BEACON MANAGER: Frame received
04-24 19:25:36.735 19998-21067/com.applications.r08y.beaconreader E/BEACON MANAGER: Frame received
04-24 19:25:37.257 19998-21073/com.applications.r08y.beaconreader E/BEACON MANAGER: Frame received
04-24 19:25:37.781 19998-21079/com.applications.r08y.beaconreader E/BEACON MANAGER: Frame received
04-24 19:25:38.343 19998-21087/com.applications.r08y.beaconreader E/BEACON MANAGER: Frame received
04-24 19:25:38.931 19998-21095/com.applications.r08y.beaconreader E/BEACON MANAGER: Frame received
04-24 19:25:39.766 19998-21102/com.applications.r08y.beaconreader E/BEACON MANAGER: Frame received
04-24 19:25:40.341 19998-21108/com.applications.r08y.beaconreader E/BEACON MANAGER: Frame received
04-24 19:25:40.940 19998-21114/com.applications.r08y.beaconreader E/BEACON MANAGER: Frame received
04-24 19:25:41.514 19998-21120/com.applications.r08y.beaconreader E/BEACON MANAGER: Frame received
04-24 19:25:42.053 19998-21126/com.applications.r08y.beaconreader E/BEACON MANAGER: Frame received
04-24 19:25:42.648 19998-21137/com.applications.r08y.beaconreader E/BEACON MANAGER: Frame received
04-24 19:25:43.182 19998-21142/com.applications.r08y.beaconreader E/BEACON MANAGER: Frame received
04-24 19:25:43.740 19998-21148/com.applications.r08y.beaconreader E/BEACON MANAGER: Frame received
04-24 19:25:44.309 19998-21158/com.applications.r08y.beaconreader E/BEACON MANAGER: Frame received
04-24 19:25:44.861 19998-21166/com.applications.r08y.beaconreader E/BEACON MANAGER: Frame received
04-24 19:25:45.421 19998-21172/com.applications.r08y.beaconreader E/BEACON MANAGER: Frame received
04-24 19:25:46.032 19998-21178/com.applications.r08y.beaconreader E/BEACON MANAGER: Beacon out of region
04-24 19:25:46.043 19998-21178/com.applications.r08y.beaconreader E/BEACON MANAGER: Frame received
04-24 19:26:00.424 19998-21314/com.applications.r08y.beaconreader E/BEACON MANAGER: Beacon entered in region
04-24 19:26:00.685 19998-21319/com.applications.r08y.beaconreader E/BEACON MANAGER: Frame received
04-24 19:26:01.264 19998-21325/com.applications.r08y.beaconreader E/BEACON MANAGER: Frame received
04-24 19:26:01.836 19998-21331/com.applications.r08y.beaconreader E/BEACON MANAGER: Frame received
04-24 19:26:02.387 19998-21335/com.applications.r08y.beaconreader E/BEACON MANAGER: Frame received
04-24 19:26:02.950 19998-21342/com.applications.r08y.beaconreader E/BEACON MANAGER: Frame received
04-24 19:26:03.513 19998-21347/com.applications.r08y.beaconreader E/BEACON MANAGER: Frame received
04-24 19:26:04.067 19998-21353/com.applications.r08y.beaconreader E/BEACON MANAGER: Frame received
04-24 19:26:04.672 19998-21362/com.applications.r08y.beaconreader E/BEACON MANAGER: Frame received
04-24 19:26:05.215 19998-21366/com.applications.r08y.beaconreader E/BEACON MANAGER: Frame received
04-24 19:26:05.805 19998-21373/com.applications.r08y.beaconreader E/BEACON MANAGER: Frame received
04-24 19:26:06.387 19998-21380/com.applications.r08y.beaconreader E/BEACON MANAGER: Frame received
04-24 19:26:06.936 19998-21385/com.applications.r08y.beaconreader E/BEACON MANAGER: Frame received
04-24 19:26:07.515 19998-21392/com.applications.r08y.beaconreader E/BEACON MANAGER: Frame received
04-24 19:26:08.103 19998-21400/com.applications.r08y.beaconreader E/BEACON MANAGER: Frame received
04-24 19:26:08.714 19998-21406/com.applications.r08y.beaconreader E/BEACON MANAGER: Frame received
04-24 19:26:09.320 19998-21411/com.applications.r08y.beaconreader E/BEACON MANAGER: Frame received
04-24 19:26:09.874 19998-21413/com.applications.r08y.beaconreader E/BEACON MANAGER: Frame received
04-24 19:26:10.498 19998-21419/com.applications.r08y.beaconreader E/BEACON MANAGER: Frame received
04-24 19:26:11.081 19998-21424/com.applications.r08y.beaconreader E/BEACON MANAGER: Beacon out of region
04-24 19:26:11.123 19998-21424/com.applications.r08y.beaconreader E/BEACON MANAGER: Frame received
```

Comment: I wonder if the app may be restarting, perhaps due to OS terminating it from memory pressure, which could cause the exit with .setRegionStatePeristenceEnabled(false).  Could you capture a similar log with .setDebug(true)?

Comment: thanks @davidgyoung, I edited my post adding the logcat resulting after `setDebug(true)`

Comment: @davidgyoung i'm sure you'll notice the frame received right after exit from region (something i forgot to mention in my post) which looks quite strange.

Comment: Sorry, I did not notice this before, but I see that the app logs `Log.e("BEACON MANAGER", "Frame received");` regardless of whether any beacons are detected.    Understand that that the `didRangeBeaconsInRegion` method is called at the end of the scan cycle (every 101ms or 501ms) regardless of whether beacons are detected.  You must look at `beacons.size()` to see if any were actually detected.  Perhaps you are really not detecting beacons for a long period of time, which is why you are getting exits.

Comment: you're right, silly me!!! i didn't make any check, i just let the app log that frame was received weather or not a frame was "really" received.

Answer (score 0):

**Part of the reason you are getting unreliable detections is the configured short scan period of 101 ms.**

Why? The Android Beacon Library will stop BLE scanning at the end of each scan period and then restart it.  It does this because some older Android devices are unable to detect multiple identical beacon advertisements unless the scan has been stopped and then started again.  Most newer devices do not behave this way.  But whenever the scan is stopped and restarted, there is a brief period (varies per device) where no packets may be detected.   With a scan cycle of ~100ms, there will be a significant percentage of time where no packets may be detected.

**A partial solution to this problem has been implemented in an unreleased version of the library available in the [ad-hoc build here]**(https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library/releases/tag/2.9.2-mpb2).  This version will detect if two identical packets are ever detected in a single scan cycle, and if so, it will no longer stop scanning at the end of each scan period.

The change above will probably resolve the issue for your device, however, **even with this release of the library, you will need a scan cycle that is at least long enough to capture two packets in a single cycle: > 200ms for a beacon transmitting at 10Hz.**  If you wish, you may start out at a longer scan period to allow this detection to take place, then after you get a didEnterRegion callback, change the scan period to something shorter.

Comment: I tried setting 501L for scantime but same result (see EDIT 2). one more question, about version 2.9.2, does this library detect only 2 identical packets or also "multiple identical packets"? in other words if i set one hour for scantime will i get all the packets beaconed during the hour? thanks.